# Building Report Column in Force Close?

Tags: android

How to build an Report column in Force close. Anyone having samples for this method? How can i done like this? Anyone knows this mean reply me.

[image: Report Column]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a Report button automatically when your **published** application crashes. It's a default feature of all applications published on the Android Market.

For developing, I would suggest [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com). Just grab their library, insert one line of code into your application's entry point and you get error reports with stack traces and cool graphs on the website.

Comment: @Kimi : So, that "report button" will create automatically when we published our project in android market.

Comment: @SPK Yes. That's a built-in feature.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) then. Its easy to use and convenient

> ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form. It is targetted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously.